# "helpful for you" or "helpful to you"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Which is more correct?

"is helpful for you" or "is helpful to you"

Context: Closing line of an email. eg. "I hope this information is helpful for you."

Answer (score 19):

"Helpful to you" is correct if you only mean that something is helpful to somebody. It really depends on the context.

Dictionaries give these examples:

1) helpful to do something

----It's very helpful to bring a dictionary in my English class.

2) helpful for/in doing something

----Reading a lot of books is helpful for writing your own books.

3) helpful for someone to do something

----It's helpful for me to take a bus instead of the subway.

4) helpful to someone

----The movie, "Frozen," is helpful to children because it gives true love another meaning.

I hope this will help you. Good day! :)

Comment: So your closing line should be "I hope this information is helpful to you."

:)

Comment: Which dictionaries? Please give attributed links in each case.

Answer (score 0):

"To" and "for" are prepositions with "you" being the object. "To" implies something is moving toward the object, while "for" implies something benefiting the object. I think "for" is the better choice.

But, as this is a closing line of an email addressed to whoever "you" is and is written for "you", why not just close with "I hope this information is helpful", or "I hope this helps;"   if you want to be less formal.

Answer (score 0):

Both "helpful for someone" and "helpful to someone" are correct (with [*for*](https://textranch.com/322430/i-hope-it-is-helpful-for-you/or/i-hope-it-is-helpful-to-you/) being somewhat more common on the Web), so the choice of preposition in this case is a matter of preference.

Additionally, there is "helpful for someone to do something" where *for* should be used.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the way you want to use the sentence:

*Helpful for you:*

Person A askes a question. Person B is the principal. Person B: "Hello, sir. Let's find the teacher with the answer which is most **helpful for you.**"

*Helpful to you:*

Person A needs help opening a door because her hands are full. Person B helps her.
Person C is her Mom. Person C said,"He was very **helpful to you**."

Hope this helps.